# Is there a tool to generate a sample application configuration by analyzing a ConfigurationSection type and its attributes?

Tags: .net, xml, reflection, configuration, documentation

I am working on an application that has a large set of configuration values, modelled and organized through the .NET configuration types from the `System.Configuration` namespace (i.e. `ConfigurationSection`, `ConfigurationProperty`, `ConfigurationElement`, etc...).  Several values are required and may or may not have defaults, while others are optional and have defaults.

I am curious if a tool or application exists that can reflect over the types that implement a configuration section and generate a sample XML, XML Schema, or other document describing the configuration.  Such a tool would be great for people that manage the application in production, and don't need to navigate several classes in a repository to determine which configuration values are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex, which amongst other things will generate a schema for a given set of configuration types.

Just what I need!